# showing text when hovering over a Raphael circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to use jQuery and RaphaelJS to:

- Create circles
- Display some information when hovering over the circle (and hiding the information when not hovering over it)

However, I can't quite get the information to display correctly... It seems to display and then immediately hide. Here's a simplified test version of the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {  
var paper = new Raphael("canvas_container", 300, 150);
paper.circle(50, 75, 30);
paper.circle(150, 75, 30);

$("circle").each(function(i) {
    $(this).mouseover(function() { 
        $("#test").append("<p>MouseOver</p>");
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#test").append("<p>MouseOut</p>");
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="canvas_container"></div>  
<div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this example, as soon as I cross into a circle, both "MouseOver" and "MouseOut" immediately get displayed. I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong events, or if there's something funky going on with Raphael.

I'm a total Javascript noob, so if I'm simply doing everything the wrong way, pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're really close here but it's only detecting the mouseover and mouseout right as you cross the borders of the circles because they're not filled in. Try filling them.

```
$(function() {  
var paper = new Raphael("canvas_container", 300, 150);
paper.circle(50, 75, 30);
paper.circle(150, 75, 30);

$("circle").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr({fill: '#FFF', stroke: '#000'});
    $(this).mouseover(function() { 
        $("#test").append("<p>MouseOver</p>");
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#test").append("<p>MouseOut</p>");
    });
});
});
```